# SSIS 2017 Importing a package with SMTP Connection Manager

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I am attempting to import a package to SSIS 2017 that contains an SMTP conneciton manager and I am receiving the following error

OLE received a packet with an invalid extension. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010112) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to create the package.  Packages that do not contain a SMTP connection manager import fine.  I have tried a blank new package with just the connection manager and I still receive the error. We have updated SQL Server to the latest cumulative update and the issue remains.  Anyone else have this issue and find a fix?